# How to concat three strings using CONCAT operator

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

How to concat three strings using CONCAT operator.

```
select concat('today',To_Char(Rts,'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss'),'date')  From  Mbl_Dishtv Partition(P_03dec2012) Where Aid=501604
```

Please suggest with CONCAT operator.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard `||` operator?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to use `CONCAT`, you'd need to make two calls

```
SELECT concat( 'today',
               concat( to_char( rts, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss'),
                       'date' ))
  FROM Mbl_Dishtv Partition(P_03dec2012) 
 WHERE Aid=501604
```

It would make much more sense, however, to use the `||` operator since it results in much cleaner code

```
SELECT 'today' ||
        to_char( rts, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') ||
        'date'
  FROM Mbl_Dishtv Partition(P_03dec2012) 
 WHERE Aid=501604
```

It also rarely makes sense to use the syntax `Partition(P_03dec2012)`.  If the table is partitioned by date, it makes much more sense to add a predicate on whatever date column you used to partition.